# Is there evidence that supports the idea that vocabulary is more important than grammar in conversation?

Tags: vocabulary, grammar, reference-request

***"Focus on your vocabulary first, then fix your grammar."***

This is a maxim that has been drilled into my head over several years of my Spanish teachers saying this, but is there really any truth to this statement? Is there any scientific research proving that you can have a longer and deeper conversation with someone if you have a strong vocabulary and a weak grammar rather than if you had a strong grammar and weak vocabulary?

Comment: Please do not use the [studies] tag. See why meta tags are bad: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/

Comment: Studies is not a meta tag.

Comment: @IͶΔ yeah, what're you talking about?

Comment: @Flimzy I believe a tag that does not describe the content of the question is. We should require references in answers if the tag seems so favorable, not introduce a tag that's not about what the question is about. Ask this from yourselves: If I needed to find this question, will I include [studies] in my search? If a tag can't serve its primary purpose, it's a bad tag.

Comment: It does describe the content of the question. The question is asking for studies. See the relevant meta post:http://meta.languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/2/13

Comment: @Flimzy Studies is easy to misread - there's already confusion between scientific-research, published-studies, studies, and learning-methods. We should figure this out.

Comment: I've changed it to scientific-research rather than studies because I feel it accurately describes the question.

Comment: Please move this discussion of tags to the meta post.

Comment: How is this a duplicate? That questions asks about whether vocab or grammar should be learned first, but mine focuses on whether "vocab first, grammar second" can be used to have a longer conversation that "grammar first, vocab second"

Comment: I would say to re-ask the question with a more specific and concrete sense of what you are hoping to get out this question. I have reviewed this question and I don't quite see the difference between this and the proposed duplicate. You have elaborated on it in the comments, but I would recommend compiling all that into its own question that is more distinct. Additionally, the similarity of the question titles may be misleading and hard for future users to determine the difference.